# How to use ArgumentParser with two short optional arguments which both accept nargs='*'

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I'm trying to equip my project with a logging functionality controlled from the cli. For that I'm using the ArgumentParser to parse the flags "-v" for verbose and "-d" for debug. It should be possible to specify optional namespaces behind them. See my snippet below. The question is at the end.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbose',
                    dest='verbose',
                    metavar='namespace',
                    nargs='*',
                    help='Sets the logging level to INFO.')
parser.add_argument('-d', '--debug,
                    dest='debug',
                    metavar='namespace',
                    nargs='*',
                    help='Sets the logging level to DEBUG.')

args = parser.parse_args()
if args.verbose:
   print('verbose: ', args.verbose)
if args.debug:
   print('debug: ', args.debug)
```

So the help usage looks something like:

```
optional arguments:
   -v [namespace [namespace ...]]
   -d [namespace [namespace ...]]
```

I'm using it together with something like the snippet below. This is just background information for you to get my intention.

```
logging_level = logging.INFO  # just as example for -v
if not namespace:
   logger = logging.getLogger()
   logger.setLevel(logging_level)
else:
   for n in namespace:
      child_logger = logger.getChild(f'{root_module_name}.{namespace}')
      child_logger.setLevel(logging_level)
```

**The problem**

1.) If I call `python my_module.py -v A -d B` the output would be like expected:

```
verbose: ['A']
debug: ['B']
```

2.) If I call `python my_module.py -v -d` the output would be like expected:

```
verbose: []
debug: []
```

3.) But if I call `python my_module.py -vd` the output looks like:

```
verbose: ['d']
debug: None
```

What I want to achieve is:

```
verbose: []
debug: []
```

4.) It's becoming even worse if I call it like `python my_module.py -vd B`

```
error: unrecognized arguments: B
```

What I want to achieve is:

```
verbose: []
debug: ['B']
```

**The question** is how to achieve my desired behaviour 3.) and 4.)?

I know that I could bypass this problem by using  `python my_module.py --verbose --debug B` which will fit my request. But this is not what I'm asking about.

Comment: very nicely asked question, could you also add some resources on what you tried to research before asking the question?

Comment: I don't see the point how does this help you to answer my question?
But as you may imagine I did some research with google which leads me of course to docs.python.org, stackoverflow and other forums...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is don't use the '-vd' input.

'-vd' is parsed as `-v d'.  Since the '-v' is a short option that takes arguments, it interprets the following string as a value, not another flag.

You would expect '-vb' to produce `['b']`, right? Why should it treat '-vd' any different?

More often people complain about '-v -d' failing to treat '-d' as an argument to '-v' (usually when '-v' expects one argument).

'-vd' would be parsed as '-v -d' if '-v' did not take an argument, such as if it was 'store_true' (`nargs=0`).

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#option-value-syntax

> For short options (options only one character long), the option and its value can be concatenated:
>
> Several short options can be joined together, using only a single - prefix, as long as only the last option (or none of them) requires a value:

Comment: **You would expect '-vb' to produce ['b'], right? Why should it treat '-vd' any different?**
I thought the **difference is the whitespace** to dinstinguish the first `-vb `as `-v -b` (which produces `verbose: []` without any additional values and an error for the unkown flag `-b`) and the second `-vd` as `-v -d` (wich produce an empty list for both, i.e. `verbose: []` and `debug: []`).

Actually I would expect that `-vd` is parsed the same way as `-v -d` and not that `d` is interpreted as an additional value for `-v`.

Comment: But you answered my question with the statement from the python docs:
**Several short options can be joined together, using only a single - prefix, as long as only the last option (or none of them) requires a value.** This means it's just not implement the way as I thought / I would like it.